# Using names-values defined in a dictionary with numpy.savez

Tags: python

I am struggling with the following problem: given a dictionary with an numpy array as a value, for example, `a={'xarray':np.ones((2,2))}`, I want to save the array into npz file with name from the dictionary key:

```
np.savez('test.npz',a.keys()=a['xarray'])
```

The error is in `a.keys`:

> ```
> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression.
> ```

I need to convert the key into an expression somehow. I tried to use `eval` function but didn't succeed.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Edit:

In order to clarify things, I want the result to be equivalent to the following:

```
np.savez('test.npz', xarray = np.ones((2,2)))
```

The name of my array is specified in the first key of the dictionary, while the array itself in the first value: `a={'xarray':np.ones((2,2))}`.

Attempting: `np.savez('test.npz',format(list(a.keys())[0])=list(a.values())[0])` returns again `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: What if there will be more than one key in the dictionary?

Comment: Well, then I want to choose which one to use. Let's say I want to use the first key (and save the corresponding numpy array, which is the first value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should try something line that: `np.savez('{}.npz'.format(list(a.keys())[0]))`. This will set a filename to a first key in a given dictionary.

The error that you get is correct since you are trying to set `a.keys()` to be the value of `a['xarray']` which is an expression. Moreover, to my very best knowledge python will not allow that.

**Edit:**
I am just after the lecture of what np.savez function does and I misunderstood you. So the correct thing (if I am correct now) is to do this:

```
kwargs = {key: a[key] for key in a.keys()}
np.savez('test.npz', **kwargs)
```

Please try and say if this is what you want :)

**Edit 2:**
For having only first key:

```
kwargs = {key: a[key] for key in [list(a.keys())[0]]}
np.savez('test.npz', **kwargs)
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I don't care about the filename but I care about the name of the saved array: it should has name specified by the first key. Please see Edit to my question.

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)